# Angular functions not working on newly-added button elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some Angular code that sends a query to a URL, gets a response, and uses that response to add buttons to the DOM. Those buttons have `ng-click` attributes. But when I click those newly-added buttons, nothing happens.

```
$scope.search=  [
    {
        query: ''
    }
];

$scope.searchStuff= function(search){
    $http({
        url: "/search",
        method: "GET",
        params: {
            query: search.query
        }
    }).then(function successfulCallback(response){
        var resultsHTML = '';
        var idList = response.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {
            var id = idList[i];
            resultsHTML += "<button ng-click=\"test("+id+")\">"+id+"</button> | "
        }
        document.getElementById("search-results").innerHTML=    resultsHTML;
    });
};

$scope.test = function(id){
    console.log(id);
}
```

HTML of the targeted area:

```
<div id="search-wrapper">
    <form novalidate>
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.query">
        <button ng-disabled="!search.query" ng-click="searchStuff(search)">SEARCH</button>
        <div id="search-results"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The `$scope.test` function never fires. What must I change to make it fire?

NOTE: I also have different interpolate providers.

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol("{[{");
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol("}]}");
```

Comment: please add your HTML code also, if you are using angular properly you don't need to generate html in javascript

Comment: Should'nt the anonymous function on the `.then` function have not any name? `.then(function(response){...})`

Comment: Your HTML for the button is incorrect. It should be '<button ng-click="test('+id+')">'+id+'</button>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you don't have a correct button html creation and it might put some error in browser console. Instead try this one:

```
resultsHTML += '<button ng-click="test("'+id+'")">'+id+'</button> | '
```

---

And instead of doing this, i would suggest you to make use of `ng-repeat` directive in the template if you have one:

```
 $scope.idList = response.data; // assign the list to scope

<!-- now use in template as below -->
<div ng-repeat="id in idList">
   <button ng-click="test(id)">{{ id }}</button>
</div>
```

Below i have added a snippet, you can see this is working as good as with last change `test(id)`

```js
var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);
app.controller('demoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.idList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  $scope.test = function(id) {
    console.log(id);
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="demoCtrl">
  <p ng-repeat="id in idList"><button ng-click="test(id)">{{id}}</button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the second way. While the `button` elements have the right number on the buttons, the `ng-click` attribute looks like `test(id)` instead of something like `test(1)`

Comment: Got this error: Error: `[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '}' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 15 of the expression [test({[{ id }]})] starting at [})]`. I have to change the interpolators from `{{` and `}}` to `{[{` and `}]}`

Comment: Seems you have issues with the structure as i have added a snippet you can see it is working as good as it can be with the last mentioned `test(id)`.

Comment: Changed the interpolators to `[[[` and `]]]`. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

Using $compile you can dynamically create elements and link them to your controller.

[Example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2yt04ztr/29/)

Create a variable that will contain an element that holds all the buttons. You compile that element.

```
var anElement = angular.element(document.getElementById("search-results"));
anElement.html('<button type="button" ng-click="main.aFunction()">New Button</button>');
$compile(anElement)($scope);
```